# "No root file system is defined" using preseed

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, preseed

I encounter a problem when installing an Ubuntu with my preseed, it gives me the error "No root file system is defined".

Does anyone know what this is due to?

```
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt
partman-partitioning partman-partitioning/choose_label select gpt

d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/$(lsblk -lbn --output SIZE,NAME | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2)"
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm_span boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                   \
    boot-root ::                                        \
        300 300 300 ext3                                \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }                  \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }        \
            mountpoint{ /boot }                         \
        .                                               \
        80000 80000 80000 ext4                          \
            method{ format } format{ }                  \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }        \
            mountpoint{ / }                             \
        .                                               \
        1000 100000 -1 ext4                             \
            method{ format } format{ }                  \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }        \
            mountpoint{ /home }                         \
        .                                               \
        2000 2000 2000 linux-swap                       \
            method{ swap } format{ }                    \
        .                                               \

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

[image: my error]

Comment: Where did you get that `partman-auto/disk` line from?  I'm not aware of being able to include a subshell command to dynamically select a disk

Comment: @AndrewLowther from the official Debian documentation : https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apbs04.html.en

Comment: I don't see anything on that page with the value close to `lsblk -lbn --output SIZE,NAME | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2`.  That value is the part that looks wrong.  If you are copying another example, I'd guess they were generating the config file using a shell script heredoc.  That would allow the subshell command to run.